# Is there a 4 port graphics card with active cooling?

Tags: graphics-card, cooling, pci, pci-express

As I wrote in the question, does anybody know a PCI/PCI express graphics card for PC that has 4 ports and is actively cooled. If possible in half-height format (but that's not a must).

Comment: http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sa=X&ei=DK2OTsbqMKaEsgLbrammAQ&ved=0CCwQvwUoAQ&q=dual+gpu+video+card&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=1083cc5305162393&biw=1190&bih=890  <-- a Dual would be a good choice, most of what I read (without knowing) the singles http://www.techspot.com/review/373-amd-radeon-6990/ can have more money or more problems for running 4 Monitors.  Links are ONLY for showing, I am NOT making a recommendation, you need a multimonitor expert for a recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VisionTek ATI Radeon HD 5570 1 GB SFF 4-Port VHDCI](http://www.visiontek.com/products/productivity-cards/vhdci.html).

[ATI FirePro™ 2460 Multi-View](http://www.amd.com/us/products/workstation/graphics/ati-firemv-2d/2460-mv/Pages/2460-firemv.aspx) only uses 20 watts so doesn't need active cooling.

There is also a [ATI FirePro 2450](http://www.amd.com/us/products/workstation/graphics/ati-firemv-2d/ati-firepro-2450-mv/Pages/ati-firepro-2450-mv.aspx) that is DVI (single link only so max 1920x1200).